# Android - QVGA screen hides some pixels

Tags: android, screen, resolution, hidden, pixel

I have a problem with missing pixels on QVGA screen on Android (all versions including 2.2). The original problem was with LinearLayout and margin="1px". It was OK on the normal screen but on QVGA there was sometimes no space between GUI controls, like if margin="0px" and not 1px. So I tried to make the example simple (to be sure that it is not a LinearLayout bug), I have just put transparent (height = 10px) and white (height = 1px) images into ImageViews into the main screen. 25% of the white images are not shown on the QVGA screen. The behaviour on the normal screen is OK. The screenshots are from the emulator but the problem exists on real devices too.

See screenshots on [my web page](http://jnem6403.sweb.cz/?cache=no).

Is it an Android bug? Can I do anything with it? Note that my original problem was with LinearLayout and margin="1px". Is there something like margin="1px_that_is_not_hidden"? (pt, dp, dip, ... don't seem to be solution)

Many thanks for a reply.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably in a compatibility mode, where Android is attempting to scale your dimensions for you, rather than thinking that you know what you're doing. It's been ages since I targeted a QVGA device, so I forget the precise details. However, I recommend you read the [multiple-screen-size instructions](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). In particular, you probably need to set `android:anyDensity="true"` in your `<supports-screens>` element.

Comment: Thank you. It was exactly that problem. I built with Android 1.5 api level 3 (to be compatible with old phones) and Android expects automatically android:anyDensity="false". So it did stupid scale... I have changed project settings to 1.6 and it works now.